# Do ivy dependency revisions have anything to do with svn's?

Tags: svn, solr, ivy, dependency-management, nutch

With no background on [ivy dependencies](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/ivyfile/dependency.html) I'm trying to [build nutch with solr 4.0](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@nutch.apache.org/msg02576.html), but I'm not sure how to change the nutch ivy dependency on solr in the ivy.xml:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.solr" name="solr-solrj" *rev="**1.4.1**"*
conf="*->default" />
```

I've no clue on where those revisions are set, as they certainly don't correspond to svn revisions. Neither do they correspond to maven versions (the version would be 4.0-SNAPSHOT). So where would I typically find the available ivy revisions?
Also, is it possible to checkout the dependency against a given svn revision? At that revision it works as I want, but I'm not sure about the latest instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Neither do they correspond to maven versions (the version would be 4.0-SNAPSHOT). So where would I typically find the available ivy revisions?

False, they correspond.

```
So where would I typically find the available ivy revisions?
```

Maven central repo ([solr in maven central repo](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.apache.solr.solr%22))

> Also, is it possible to checkout the dependency against a given svn revision? 
>   mvn install locally, and then refer to your snapshot. 
>   For Solr:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.solr" name="solr-solrj" rev="4.0-SNAPSHOT"
            conf="*->default"/>
```